# Why can it not enter and run the main function?

Tags: c, depth-first-search

It's a adjacency matrix about DFS.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int visited[1000];

typedef struct MGraph {
    int vexs[1000];
    int arc[1000][1000];
    int numVertexes, numEdges;
} MGraph;

void DFS(MGraph G, int i)
{
    visited[i] = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < G.numVertexes; j++)
        if (visited[j] == 0 && G.arc[i][j] == 1)
            DFS(G, j);
}

void DFSTrverse(MGraph G)
{
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < G.numVertexes; i++)
        visited[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < G.numVertexes; i++)
    {
        if (visited[i] == 0)
        {
            num++;
            DFS(G, i);
        }
    }
    printf("%d", num - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;
    MGraph g;
    scanf("%d %d", &g.numVertexes, &g.numEdges);
    for (i = 0; i < g.numVertexes; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < g.numVertexes; j++)
            g.arc[i][j] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < g.numEdges; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &j, &k);
        g.arc[j-1][k-1] = 1;
    }
    DFSTrverse(g);
}
```

I can't find what's wrong with my program. Can't even run the `main` function and it ends.

I tried putting `printf(1)` in the beginning of the `main` function, but nothing outputs, then the program terminates.

Comment: `printf(1);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `int arc[1000][1000];` <-- Your `main` function will try to allocate over 4MB on the stack.  That's quite a lot. You might want to consider allocating space on the heap instead.

Comment: And you are passing around objects of that type *by value*, which will use that much space again at every call depth.  Usually one wants functions to exchange pointers to structures instead of exchanging structures by value.  For very large structures, "usually" takes a value very close to "always".

Comment: Thank you so much and I know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

The program does not run because of a **Stack Overflow**:

In the `main` function, you define a local structure `g` of type `MGraph`.  This type occupies 4004008 bytes, which is too much for your target as compiled by your compiler.

Furthermore, you pass this structure by value to `DFSTrverse`, and recursively to `DFS` which requires an additional 4MB per call... way too much for any system for even a moderately complex graph.

Note also the passing the structure by value means you do not update the original structure, so the code does not work at all.

There are multiple ways for you to work around this problem:

- declare `g` as a global variable;
- allocate `g` from the heap and use a pointer in `main` and `DFSTrverse`.

Here is a modified version for the latter approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct MGraph {
    int vexs[1000];
    int arc[1000][1000];
    int numVertexes, numEdges;
} MGraph;

void DFS(const MGraph *g, int i, int *visited) {
    visited[i] = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < g->numVertexes; j++)
        if (visited[j] == 0 && g->arc[i][j] == 1)
            DFS(g, j, visited);
}

void DFSTrverse(const MGraph *g) {
    int visited[1000];
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < g->numVertexes; i++) {
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < g->numVertexes; i++) {
        if (visited[i] == 0) {
            num++;
            DFS(g, i, visited);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", num - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    int i, j, k;
    MGraph *g = calloc(sizeof(*g));
    if (g == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate MGraph");
        return 1;
    }
    if (scanf("%d %d", &g->numVertexes, &g->numEdges) != 2 || g->numVertexes > 1000) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < g->numEdges; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d %d", &j, &k) != 2 || j < 1 || j > 1000 || k < 1 || k > 1000) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        g->arc[j - 1][k - 1] = 1;
    }
    DFSTrverse(g);
    return 0;
}
```